# Birthday-Type Problem

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

What’s the probability that $2$ kids are born on the same day of the week if there are $6$ kids in the room?

Comment: It is easier to compute the probability they are all born on different days.  Can you do that?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You're far more likely to get a better answer if you show us the work you've done on the problem.

Comment: The question needs improvement: does '2 kids' mean 'exactly 2 kids', '2 or more kids' or 'one pair of kids and no other pair' etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are $7^7$ ways in total.

The number of ways that all kids are born on different days is $7!$

Thus, the probability is $$\frac{7!}{7^7}=\frac{6!}{7^6}$$

Comment: How did you come up with that probability? If we had 7 children, instead of 6, what would the probability be that all children were born on different days?

Comment: I changed it. I think the old one was incorrect.

Comment: My comment was just to think a bit more about the correct way to think about it. : ) However, in the specific problem here we deal with 6 children, not 7.